# Why is [super loadView] or [super viewDidLoad] required?

Tags: objective-c, ios, superclass

What happens when [super loadView] or [super viewDidLoad] is written? I tried to remove the code but the stack overflows and goes into infinite loop. Can someone please explain why is this required?

Comment: 'but the **stack overflow** s' - LOL. Was that phrasing your intention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, when you override `loadView`, to create your own views manually, you should **NOT** call the superclass's implementation. This is because you would be creating a view manually, and using those *instead of* the view that would be created by `UIViewController`'s implementation. (See the `loadview` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW1).)

But when you override `viewDidLoad`, you should indeed call the superclass's implementation. This is because `UIViewController`'s implementation of `viewDidLoad` does some internal bookkeeping, and so you want to run your custom `viewDidLoad` code *in addition to* what the superclass does.

Comment: But even while using loadView, we need to override the superclass. U have mentioned that we dont need to override the loadView method. Can u please explain why? @yuji

Comment: Huh?? I didn't say that "we dont[sic] need to override the loadView method." I'm saying that **if** you implement `loadView` in a subclass, then you probably don't need to call the superclass's implementation. Please read the documentation I linked to for details.

Answer (score 3):

It calls the method from your superclass. Lets say its NSObject. The names of these methods explain:
loadView is the NSObject method which loads the view, viewDidLoad is the NSObject method which processes that the view has loaded... along those lines
The method itself in your view controller "viewDidLoad" and maybe "loadView" has no code that does the above... its just for customization since you can't modify the original .m methods...

To find out your superclass go to .h file:

```
   @interface MyViewController : MySuperClass //thats it!
```

Answer (score 2):

The underlying class needs to do some bookkeeping of its own to be ready before you start putting UI on top of it. In Android the corresponding app will actually intentionally crash by throwing a you-didn't-call-super-first exception.